# What is the difference between "using = " and "using"?

Tags: c++

I am aware of the most obvious differences; ie. that `using` allows you to specify a new name for the type being introduced, but what is the difference between the following two statements:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public X<T>
{
  using Base = X<T>;
  using Type = typename Base::Type; // statement 1
  using typename Base::Type; // statement 2
};
```

I've noticed that sometimes statement two doesn't work as expected. For example, I might get an error like *"error: no member named 'Type' in X"*.

So how do these statements differ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: @Pradhan I don't see how these are related.

Comment: It makes no sense to use `typename` outside the declaration or definition of a template. In such a context, the answer pointed to shows you how and why it should be used.

Comment: I realise that the title might have attracted drive-by close requests, so I've changed it. **Please read the question before close-voting**.

Comment: Retracted close-vote.

Comment: @Pradhan Thanks. Also, I've edited the code to clarify why I'm using the `template` keyword in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using T1 = T2;` is new (as of C++11) syntax that provides an alternative to `typedef`. `using Type = typename X::Type;` means exactly the same thing as `typedef typename X::Type Type;`.

`using typename X::Type;` is older syntax, specifically intended for inheriting members from base classes. Normally, the `typename` would be redundant, normally you would be able to write `using X::Type;` instead, but in the case of template base classes, you may need `typename` to prevent `X::Type` from being parsed as a non-type member.

An example where they differ is

```
struct A {
  typedef int i;
};

struct B {
  using i = typename A::i; // valid
  using typename A::i; // invalid, A is not a base class of B
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The first form introduces a new name for a type, it's alternative syntax for `typedef`.

The second form redeclares a name for use in the current scope. i.e. it makes a name from another scope usable in the current scope qualifying it, e.g. `using std::swap` means you can just say `swap` instead of `std::swap`.

Comment: notable difference to `typedef`: `template <...> using .. = ...`

Comment: @stefan, no need to complicate things, the question doesn't ask about that form of alias declaration.

Comment: Sure, it's just a comment, I don't force you to include that in the answer ;-) You didn't write "equivalent", so it's absolutely fine.